# Return whole document from aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using the following query to fetch one most recent comment for every post in database:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "post_id": {
                "$in": [ObjectId("52c5ce24dca32d32740c1435"), ObjectId("52c5ce24dca32d32740c15ad")]
            }
        }
     },
     {
         "$sort": {"_id": -1}
     },
     {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$post_id",
            "lastComment": {
                "$first": "$_id"
            }
        }
     }
])
```

I expect it to return the whole comment's document but it only returns the `_id` field of each document. So what would be the proper way to get all most recent comments as a whole document (or at least include some other fields)?

Comment: Are the comments within a document field? You are selecting the first _id of the group, but if you have another field with post comments, you should change "$_id". Maybe an example document can help us.

Comment: Comments are stored in a separate collection where each comment is a separate document and each of them have a reference to the corresponding post's document via the "post_id" field. If that answers your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently you cannot get the whole `comment` document via single `$first` operator. But you can include other necessary fields (similar to `_id` field) during `$group` step:

```
{
    "$group": {
        _id: "$post_id",
        lastComment: { "$first": "$_id" },
        field_1: { "$first": "$field_1" },
        field_2: { "$first": "$field_2" },
        // ...
        field_N: { "$first": "$field_N" }
    }
}
```

---

According to this JIRA ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5916, the whole document will be available to return from aggregation operations from **2.5.3 version**. It will be possible using new variables: `$$ROOT` or `$$CURRENT`:

```
{
    "$group": {
        _id: "$post_id",
        lastComment: { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks good but in the end result instead of getting json objects like this {},{},{} . I'm getting {lastComment:{actualEntireObj}},{lastComment:{actualEntireObj}},{lastComment:{actualEntireObj}}. How to unwrap the object from lastComment and return as normal way {},{},{} using $project(aggregation) in MongoDB? Any idea ?

Comment: yes I've found the required solution, upvote. thanks for the above hint..

Answer (score 4):

As suggested, we can do :

```
 {
    "$group": {
        _id: "$post_id",
        lastComment: { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }
    }
}
```

and then do use { '$replaceRoot': { 'newRoot':  '$lastComment' } } on any mongodb server 3.4 or above to unwrap object from **`{lastComment:{actualEntireObj}},{lastComment:{actualEntireObj}}`** to **`{},{}`** this way it will get embedded $$ROOT document to the top level and replaces all other fields like **_id** returning from $group stage of aggregation.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "post_id": {
                "$in": [ObjectId("52c5ce24dca32d32740c1435"), ObjectId("52c5ce24dca32d32740c15ad")]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": { "_id": -1 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: "$post_id",
            lastComment: { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }
        }
    },
    { '$replaceRoot': { 'newRoot': '$lastComment' } }
])
```

Comment: you can use $push instead of $first if you've multiple documents !!